# Maven not compiling class and there is no class files in war file

Tags: java, maven-2

iam converting my project to maven.
I see in war file there is no class file available.

Below is the pom.xml and project structure.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>RetailProducts</groupId>
  <artifactId>RetailProducts</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>RetailProducts</name>

  <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
                <!-- Tomcat 6 need this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>JavaServerFaces</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
      <!-- <configuration> section added to pick up the WEB-INF/web.xml inside WebContent -->
      <configuration>
         <webResources>
            <resource>
               <directory>WebContent</directory>
            </resource>
         </webResources>
      </configuration>
   </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Project structure**

[image]

Comment: downvoters please mention for what you are downvoting so i can correct myself

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From my point of view your project structure isn't as maven expects.

**In order to solve your problem do the following:**

1. First rename your package *retail.web.mbean* to *main.java.retail.web.mbean* (after the process your package will be still named *retail.web.mbean*), this will create the folder structure necessary for maven.
2. Right click on the project, Maven > Update Project Configuration.

After this process you will have the same structure you had before starting the project but maven will know where to find the source code.

Additionally, you can create a resource folder and test folders with the following structure:

```
Project
  src
    main
      java
      resources
    test
      java
      resources
```

This would be the standard maven project structure.

Comment: please can you check this question too http://stackoverflow.com/q/16383877/668970

Answer (score 21):

By default Maven expects the Java sources to be in **src/main/java** but your project structure has the sources in **src**. I would recommend that to you adhere to the [standard Maven directory](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) layout.

If you don't want to do that then you can use the [sourceDirectory](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Directories) build setting as should below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: When I imported my maven project in eclipse it did not recognize it as a Dynamic Web Project, so it wasn't generating the classes. When I added 
`<sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>` in the pom it generated and it worked. Amazing !!

Comment: my problem was with java version. I had 1.8.101 and had to update to 1.8.144, then maven could recognize sources files at src/main/java

Comment: tips: and for test directory, you could add your own dir e.g: <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/test</testSourceDirectory>

Comment: does this generate .java file or .class file in the target

Answer (score -5):

You can use the following lines of code in POM.xml to include java files in war that you have created.
Bydefault war exclude .java files while packaging.

```
<resources>
    <resource>
    <directory>src</directory>
    <includes>
    <include>**/*.java</include>
    </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: Just so you know what you've suggested. That will put .java files in the target/classes which is not what you want. You want to build them to .class files first.