# how to configure war dependent on ejb jar and create ear file combinedly

Tags: java, maven

I am new to Maven and also learning it. I have two projects in eclipse one is retailproducts which contains UI stuff and other project is ejb project retailservice. I written separate pom files for both the projects and able to generate war and jar files.  What i have to do is.

a) I have to configure jar file in war file as jar file contains ejb stuff which is required by webappliction
b) after creating war file i have to create ear file which will have war file in turn jar file.

how can I do this.

I am providing both the pom.xmls here.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>RetailProducts</groupId>
  <artifactId>RetailProducts</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>RetailProducts</name>

  <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
                <!-- Tomcat 6 need this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>JavaServerFaces</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
      <!-- <configuration> section added to pick up the WEB-INF/web.xml inside WebContent -->
      <configuration>
         <webResources>
            <resource>
               <directory>WebContent</directory>
            </resource>
         </webResources>
      </configuration>
   </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>RetailService</groupId>
  <artifactId>RetailService</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>RetailService</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies> 
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>ejbModule</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>ejbModule</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: what you want is to add the JAR built by one project into the other?

Comment: @that jar contains session beans and jpa data persistence files, iam using JSF where Managed Beans will have dependency on ejb layer, as from Managed Beans iam calling remote ejb.

Comment: ok, couldn't you just add the dependency `<groupId>RetailService</groupId><artifactId>RetailService</artifactId><version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>` to the `RetailProducts` project?

Comment: Yes that is the only solution

Comment: Your answer is here :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31790288/435912

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When building Java EE 5.0 application containing both WAR and EJB modules you usually have 3 Maven modules that define:

1. Web application
2. EJBs
3. EAR

You have first two but don't have EAR module. It should look something like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Retail</groupId>
    <artifactId>RetailEAR</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                    <skinnyWars>true</skinnyWars>
                    <version>5</version>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>RetailService</groupId>
            <artifactId>RetailService</artifactId>
            <type>ejb</type>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>RetailProducts</groupId>
            <artifactId>RetailProducts</artifactId>
            <type>war</type>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Then when you package EAR module it handles dependencies for web application. The parameter `skinnyWars` controls if dependencies should be duplicated inside WAR or not. Usually you don't want them inside WAR since they are accessible to web application from EAR itself.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't including the `EJB` dependency inside the EAR project's `pom.xml` as I included it as a dependency in the WAR project's `pom.xml`. This caused the `EJB` to not startup. After adding the `EJB` dependency back to EAR project's pom.xml everything is back to normal. Also, `skinnyWars` is a nice configuration.

Comment: @fnt do you have to execute "mvn install" on each module?

Comment: @user3111525 Execute it for what?

Comment: @fnt if I change something on RetailProducts module, do I have to install it on local repository before I can package my ear?

Comment: @user3111525 I don't know your delivery procedure. This is a generic question about Maven and I don't think it has anything to do with my answer to the original question. Maven build lifecycle is described in detail at http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html