# Maven ear project with ejb and war modules

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss

im working on a web application with maven and Jboss 7 wich conatins 3 modules ejb ear and war so the war will have the ejb as dependancy  and the ejb will be in the same time a module of the ear so when i do this i get the same ejb twice this tree

```
ear
...Mywar
........Myejb
...Myejb
```

is this structure is correct or i should change another

the pom.xml for the war :

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>tn.war.ep</groupId>
  <artifactId>businessModule</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>  
     .....
     <dependency>
    <groupId>tn.linckia.epgp</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejbModule</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

the pom.xml for the ear :

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>tn.war.ep</groupId>
  <artifactId>earModule</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>

  <build>
  <plugins>

    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
        <modules>
          <webModule>
            <groupId>tn.war.ep</groupId>
            <artifactId>businessModule</artifactId>
            <bundleFileName>businessModule.war</bundleFileName>
            <contextRoot>/businessModule</contextRoot>
          </webModule>
          <ejbModule>
            <groupId>tn.war.ep</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejbModule</artifactId>
           <bundleFileName>ejbModule.jar</bundleFileName>
          </ejbModule>
        </modules>
        <displayName>Security</displayName>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
  <finalName>AuthModule</finalName>
</build>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>tn.war.ep</groupId>
    <artifactId>businessModule</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>war</type>
  </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>tn.war.ep</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejbModule</artifactId>
           <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
          <type>ejb</type>
          </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 4):

Right way to configure EAR Module is to have the EJB jar dependency with "provided" scope in WAR module and having EJB jar directly under EAR like the below:

```
EAR
|
|-lib/someutil.jar
|-EJB.jar
|-my-web.war
|  |-WEB_INF/lib
|    |-coolutil.jar
|-EJB2.jar
```

But the my-web.war can dependent on the any EJB.jar, but its resolved in runtime by container. So, mark that ejb dependency as "provided" (by container) in WAR's pom.xml.

Answer (score 1):

**Option : #1**

Yon don't even need a ear. 
You can just put all your EJBs as jars inside the war.
Just add the EJB projects as dependencies in your War project.

**Option : #2**

If you still want EAR. All EJB projects output should be jars. And web project output should be war. And at last these EJB jars and web war would be placed in one EAR. This is a old fashion way, to keep it simple you could follow the method which I explained above in Option #1.

Comment: I am asked to deliver all modules in an ear wich contain an ejb module and war module ... but my problem is: is itcorrect to have the ejb twice at the tree ?

Comment: Fine. No you should not have it twice. Remove the EJB dependency in the WAR project. Then you will not have it under the WAR. If you still have problem post your pom.xml

Comment: i added the pom.xml for the ear and the war

Comment: the problem how i will get the ejb dependencieds in my war because i will need to instanciate the entities from the ejb into my war

Comment: Remove the ejb dependency in WAR, deploy the application as EAR and check.

Comment: it does not even compile

Comment: To solve it, change the scope of the dependencies to "provided" in war.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and changing the ejb packaging tag from ejb to jar in the ejb modules pom.xml fixed the issue.  No idea why!

Comment: Its because ejb packaging is treated completely different from jar packaging in maven-ear-plugin.